# Function with css variable stored in sass variable returns undefined operation

Tags: css, sass

I have a sass function like this:

```
$base-size: var(--base-size, 14px);

@function calc($size) {
  $newSize: $size / $base-size;
  @return #{$newSize}rem;
}
```

`--base-size` is defined in :root but also has a fallback value as you can see.
While compiling it always gives me this error:

Undefined operation "10px/var(--base-size, 14px) * 1em".
 @return ($target / $context) * 1em;

When I write `$base-size: 14px;`, everything works fine. Is it not possible to use css variables in sass functions like this?

Comment: Your mixing concepts.  Stick to one... if you are using SASS I would choose SASS variables.  The only time I use CSS Variables is when I am not using SASS. I have never tried the assignment you are choosing to use but my guess something is getting lost in translation.

Comment: sass is not meant to interpret css files but  compile scripts and include them into css file that the browser will treat. It cannot deal with css custom properties, only browsers does.